# getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') error

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, display, getelementbyid

I know this question has been asked before but I went through them and still couldn't find out what is wrong. I want to show/hide a div using a javascript function and i used an external script with an onclick function. Please explain why this error is happening.

This is my html:

```
<div class="payment">
            <fieldset style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),url(img/orangekat.jpg);">

                <h2>Payment</h2><br>
                <p>Choose Payment Method</p>

                <input type="button" name="paycod" class="cod" value="Cash on Delivery" onclick="callForm1()" >

                <div  id="when" style="display: none;">
                    <form method="post" action="" >
                        <label>What would be the most convinient time for you to recieve the package?</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="when" id="" value="Weekdays">
                        <label>Weekdays</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="when" id="" value="Weekends">
                        <label>Weekends</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="morn" name="morn" value="Morning">
                        <label > Morning</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="after" name="after" value="Afternoon">
                        <label > Afternoon</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="eve" name="eve" value="Evening">
                        <label > Evening</label><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="subcod" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>

                <input type="button" name="paycard" class="card" value="Credit/Debit Card" onclick="callForm2()">

                <div id="paycard" style="display: none;">
                    <form method="post" action="">
                    <label>Name On Card*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cardname" placeholder="Eg:- Kavishki Perera" required><br>
                    <label>Card Number*</label>
                    <input type="" name="cardnum" placeholder="1111-1111-1111-1111" required><br>
                    <label>Expire Month & Year*</label>
                    <input type="date" name="exp" id="" required><br>
                    <label>CVC*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cvc" placeholder="123" required><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="savepay" name="savepay" value="Save My Details">
                    <label >Save My Payment Details</label><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="btnsub" value="Pay">
                    <input type="reset" name="btnres" value="Clear">
                </form>

                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

this is the javascript:

```
var form1=document.getElementById('when');
var form2=document.getElementById('paycard');

console.log(form1);
console.log(form2);

var formVisibility1=form1.style.display;
var formVisibility2=form2.style.display;

function callForm1() {
  if (formVisibility1==='block') 
  {
    formVisibility1='none';
  }
  else 
  {
    formVisibility1='block';
  }
}

function callForm2() {
  if (formVisibility2==='block') 
  {
    formVisibility2='none';
  }
  else
  {
    formVisibility2='block';
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ivar i tried these methods but they didn't work for this.

Comment: Without a working [mcve] we can't tell you much more. If that is your HTML and the JavaScript is loaded in after the HTML, then [it should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv61qxm0/). Do note that `formVisibility1` is initialized with the value of `form1.style.display` the way it was when the script was executed. It is not an alias for `form1.style.display`. Changing `formVisibility1` doesn't change `form1.style.display`.

Comment: @Ivar changing formVisibility1 to form1.style.display worked. thank you.